# Selecting all visible rows after a search using 'selectAll' button in Data-table

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have initialized a data-table having id **example** like this -

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[4, "asc"]],
    select: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5',
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            orientation: 'portrait',
            pageSize: 'LEGAL'
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            pageSize: 'LEGAL',
            title: 'Visible rows'
        },
        {
            extend: 'selectAll',
            className: 'selectall'
        }
    ],
    language: {
        buttons: {
            selectAll: "Select all rows"
        }
    }
});
```

Than i have tried to select all rows after a search with below code when **selectAll** button is clicked -

```
table.on('search.dt', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".selectall").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var rows_after_search = table.rows({search: 'applied'}).nodes();
        rows_after_search.each(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });
    });
});
```

I am kind of lost after this. **selectAll** is still selecting all the rows at that page.

To elaborate, suppose there are 10 rows at the current page of Data-table. After search it is showing 2 rows. Now i want to select 2 rows while **selectAll** button is clicked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your general problem is that you are not resetting deselected (not filtered) rows. You are just toggling `.selected` for filtered rows, ultimately ending up in all rows being selected. Also, I would place the code in the `action` method, since you are in fact overriding the selectAll default functionality.

```js
{
   extend: 'selectAll',
   className: 'selectall',
   action : function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     table.rows({ page: 'all'}).nodes().each(function() {
       $(this).removeClass('selected')
     })
     table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).nodes().each(function() {
       $(this).addClass('selected');        
     })
   }
}
```

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/sqmz7z76/**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Once i thought about it in your way (removing selected class) and tried it but never worked. May be, positioning code at action method is the only way. Thanks again. :)

Comment: This worked. However, iterating using `each` is rather slow

Comment: Not downvoting but this solution only SEEMS to work. It changes the correct classes but doesn't actually select the item (so basically if you selected something you cannot deselect it with deselect all for example, or get it or... anything really).

Comment: @zozo, thanks for the heads up! Weird. I will look into it when I come home.

Answer (score 14):

davidkonrad's code is mostly right, but it's not using the official methods. This is the correct code to use:

```
{
  extend: 'selectAll',
  className: 'selectall',
  action : function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).deselect();
    table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).select();
  }
}
```

Instead of simply toggling the class 'selected', it calls the method 'select()', which in turn, enables the "Deselect all" button and displays the footer text telling you how many rows have been selected.

Comment: It should probably deselect all rows `table.rows().deselect()` instead of just the filtered ones.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it triggers the actual select/deselect mechanism instead of just toggling classes.

Answer (score 2):

h0dges' answer is closer than davidkonrad's, but will select everything regardless of the current page if there is no filter applied (so all loaded records, even if you only have 10 records shown on the page). Here's the best overall method I was able to come up with.

```
{
  extend: 'selectAll',
  className: 'selectall',
  action : function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    roleTable.rows({ page: 'current'}).select();
    roleTable.rows({ search: 'removed'}).deselect();

  }
}
```

This will select all records on the current page and remove anything previously selected that was filtered out with the search function.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    extend: 'selectAll',
    className: 'selectall',
    action : function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).deselect();
        table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).select();
    }
}
```

This is the solution for new versions

Comment: Why duplicate another answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found this works to get array of row data for filtered & only selected rows (when using the select plugin):

```
<head>
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.4/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.4/js/dataTables.select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<script>    
    var selectedRows = table.rows({ search: 'applied' }).rows(".selected").data();
</script>
```