# Select only filtered rows using select all button that comes with select extension in shiny's DT package

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I am trying to select only filtered rows using select all button that comes with select extension in shiny's DT package but it selects all the rows. 
Here's the sample shiny [app](https://radhikesh.shinyapps.io/selectextension/)

Below is the reproducible code for the app:

```
library(DT)
data(mpg)
# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Select only filtered rows using selectall button"),

    br(),
    br(),

    DT::dataTableOutput("table")


)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(mpg, escape=F,
                  rownames=F,
                  filter = 'top',
                  #  colnames = c("Data Type","Variable","Description", "Filename"),
                  class = "compact hover row-border",
                  extensions = c('Scroller','Select', 'Buttons'),

                  options = list(
                      select = list(style = "multi", items = "row"),
                      columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
                      language = list(
                          info = 'Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ variables'),
                      deferRender = TRUE,
                      scrollY = 500,
                      scroller = TRUE,
                      dom = "Blfrtip",
                      buttons = c('selectAll', 'selectNone')
                  ),
                  selection="none"
        ) }, server = F
    )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I think I may have to add some custom javascript to fix this but I am not good with it.
Can anyone help or give any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow I managed to figure out the solution for my question. Posting it here, so it might help others. I got help from couple of places. [Datatable document](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.extend) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40363328/6090977)

Using these helps, I extended my selectall button functionality and also extended it for deselectall button (deselect any filtered rows).

Here's the updated shiny [app](https://radhikesh.shinyapps.io/selectextension/)

Below is the updated code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data(mpg)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Select only filtered rows using selectall button"),
    
    br(),
    br(),
    
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    
        
    
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(mpg, escape=F,
                  rownames=F,
                  filter = 'top',
                  #  colnames = c("Data Type","Variable","Description", "Filename"),
                  class = "compact hover row-border",
                  extensions = c('Scroller','Select', 'Buttons'),
                  
                  options = list(
                      select = list(style = "multi", items = "row"),
                      columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
                      language = list(
                          info = 'Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ variables'),
                      deferRender = TRUE,
                      scrollY = 500,
                      scroller = TRUE,
                      dom = "Blfrtip",
                      buttons = list(list(extend='selectAll',className='selectAll',
                                text="select all rows",
                                action=DT::JS("function () {
                                var table = $('.dataTable').DataTable();
                                table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).deselect();
                                table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).select();
                }")
                                ), list(extend='selectNone',
                                        text="DeselectAll",
                                        action=DT::JS("function () {
                                var table = $('.dataTable').DataTable();
                                table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).select();
                                table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).deselect();
                }")
                                ))
                      
                  ),
                  selection="none"
        ) }, server = F
    )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope this help others.