# Shiny DT, custom button to select filtered rows

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I would like to include custom buttons as extensions to the `data.table` in the minimal reproducible example below. This example is essentially taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61897668/select-only-filtered-rows-using-select-all-button-that-comes-with-select-extensi).

As I have several `data.tables` in my application, I tried to generalize the node in the `JS` code of the `action` definition of the button with the function `var table = $(this.api().table().node()).DataTable();`, which does not work. If I insert `var table = $('#DataTables_Table_0').DataTable();` it works fine, but is not general any more.

Any help is really appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Select only filtered rows using selectall button"),

  br(),
  br(),

  DT::dataTableOutput("tableTest")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$tableTest <- DT::renderDataTable({

    datatable(mtcars,
      escape = F,
      rownames = F,
      filter = 'top',
      class = "compact hover row-border",
      extensions = c('Scroller', 'Select', 'Buttons'),

      options = list(
        select = list(style = "multi", items = "row"),
        columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
        language = list(info = 'Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ variables'),
        deferRender = TRUE,
        scrollY = 500,
        scroller = TRUE,
        dom = "Blfrtip",
        buttons =
          list(
            list(extend='selectAll',
              className='selectAll',
              text="select all rows",
              action = DT::JS(
                "function () {
                var table = $(this.api().table().node()).DataTable();
                table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).deselect();
                table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).select();
              }")
            ),
            list(extend='selectNone',
              text="DeselectAll",
              action = DT::JS(
                "function () {
                var table = $(this.api().table().node()).DataTable();
                table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).select();
                table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).deselect();
              }")
            ))
      ),
      selection = "none"
    ) }, server = F
  )
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried, but I think you can do:

```
action = JS(
  "function(e, table, node, config) {",
  "  table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).deselect();",
  "  table.rows({ search: 'applied'}).select();",
  "}"
)
```